# Java поиск строк в файле по ключевому слову

Tags: java, парсер

Есть лог файл в текстовом формате, весом 4gb.  Структура файла - это N строк весом примерно 200 байт.
Необходимо получать строки (добавлять их в массив), в которых есть ключевое слово.
Очень важна скорость получения информации. 
На данный момент реализовано следующим образом:

```
public List<String> readFileByFilter(String fileName, String filter) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();        
    while (reader.ready()) {
        String tmp = reader.readLine();
        if (tmp.matches(".*"+ filter +".*")) {
            list.add(tmp);
        }
    }
    reader.close();
    return list;
}
```

Подскажите, есть ли возможность сделать производительней (быстрей) данный участок кода?

Comment: Можете попробовать применить `BufferedReader` с try ресурсами вместо использования метода `close`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Строка

```
if (tmp.matches(".*"+ filter +".*")) {
```

вызываемая в цикле, это уникальнейший провал производительности

1. На каждой итерации цикла конструируется новая строка
2. Используется регулярное выражение вместо простого поиска по тексту

Замените эту строку на

```
if (tmp.contains(filter)) {
```

Comment: Спасибо, я протестировал. Производительность увеличилась более чем в два раза. А есть ли у Вас идея как еще можно реализовать эту задачу, чтобы повысить производительность?

Comment: Да. Отказаться от `BufferedReader` и перейти на потоки

Comment: Антон, не затруднит ли Вас написать пример с потоками?